# cannot find -luuid error make

Tags: centos, make

I am using centos7 and am trying to build this https://github.com/daveti/prov-tools/tree/master/system however I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
```

I did yum install with libuuid and it says that its installed, but I'm missing libuuid.a it seems. However there is no libuuid-static. Is there a package I'm missing or can I change my makefile so that i makes.

Here is the makefile

```
PREFIX ?= /usr  

CFLAGS ?= -Wall -Werror 
CFLAGS += -std=gnu99 -static

BINARIES = pbang ncred elijah fixbang
OBJECTS = plog

all: $(BINARIES)

clean:
    $(RM) $(BINARIES) $(addsuffix .o,$(OBJECTS))

install: $(addprefix install-,$(BINARIES))

install-%: %
    install -D $< $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/sbin/$<

ncred elijah: plog.o

pbang: LDLIBS += -lz -luuid

.PHONY: all clean install
```

EDIT : 
I verified that I have libuuid.so using find, but I'm not sure how I would link to this?

Answer (score 2):

You need **libuuid-devel** , this package provide libraries for compiling .

**libuuid** provide libraries fro running

Comment: I have both libuuid and libuuid-devel installed.

Comment: Still can't find the libraries

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat gives rationale on [bug 596898](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=596898). Essentially, static libraries, particularly for basic infrastructure, are *very* strongly discouraged (it has been ages since the dynamic library machinery last acted up on me, so I heartily agree).

In general, I'd try looking for the package containing the presumable file name, something like:

```
dnf provides /usr/lib64/libuuuid.a
```

(`dnf` is smart in that it also recognizes e.g. pieces of TeX or Perl/Python modules by name). Then you can ask for further information an any hits, and decide what to do. If in a hurry and feeling reckless:

```
dnf -y install /usr/lib64/libuuuid.a
```